# Adding domain to Virtual Machine

Tags: dns, virtual-machine

I currently have a linux virtual machine that is setup with my school, using one of my school's domains. I recently bought a domain with GoDaddy, and I am interested in switching my virtual machine over to my domain. I'll be honest, I don't really know the first thing about configuring a DNS.

On the VM already, I have the apache server setup, so I know it is properly connected to the web using the domain I was given by my school.

Obviously, I know I'll have to change some of the basic stuff like the /etc/hosts file to switch to the new domain, but what else will I have to do in order to get my VM switched to the new domain? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, add DNS records to point to the VM.
First create a DNS zone file with the provider from where you bought a domain. 
Go to dns settings, create a A record and point it to the VM by adding the IP address of the VM.

Once this is done, wait for the TTL you have set, and now you should be able to access the VM from the domain.